# UIMenuController Has Zero Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimenucontroller

**I really went through every other question on SO related to this topic. But none helped me so far.**

I am trying to show a `UIMenuController` on a `UIView`. I therefore subclassed the `UIView` and implemented all the required methods already.
In the `UIViewController` I instantiate a `UIGestureRecognizer` and add it to the custom `UIView`. This works just fine. I can also handle the long press gesture. It is just that the `UIMenuController` **won't show up!**

```
@interface CopyableView : UIView
@end

@implementation CopyableView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"_CAN BECOME 1. RESPONDER_");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action
              withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"_CAN PERFORM ACTION_");
    return (action == @selector(copy:));
}

- (void)copy:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"_COPY_");
}

@end


@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CopyableView *myView;

@end

@implementation InfoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myView addGestureRecognizer:[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)]];
}

- (void)handleLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"__ %i __", [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible);

        [self.myView becomeFirstResponder];

        UIMenuItem *item = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy"
                                                      action:@selector(copy:)];
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:@[item]];
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setTargetRect:CGRectMake(33, 33, 33, 33)
                                                        inView:self.myView];
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:YES
                                                       animated:NO];

        NSLog(@"__ %i __", [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible);
        NSLog(@"#### %@ ####", NSStringFromCGRect([UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuFrame));
    }
}
```

Checking `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible` returns `true` at the end of the method. So things seem to work. Still I see nothing happening.
The frame of the `UIMenuController` is `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}` which I cannot understand.

Comment: Are the logs in your CopyableView working?

Comment: I have tested the same code on simulator 8.2 on iPad, its working fine for me. Only one issue it's showing two copy instead of only one. Please check your IBOutlet  for 'myView'.

Comment: @JasperPol only canBecomeFirstResponder

Comment: @VijayMasiwal Thx. Is there any possibility that the UIMenuController actually gets hidden by something above it? How can I make sure to have it above every other layer on the screen?